# Import on demand a module inside method class in javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, babeljs, webpack-4, es6-class, dynamic-import

I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this scenario:

1. Load on demand a module through dynamic import inside a method of a class
2. Once loaded with dynamic import, make calls their methods

[Link to codesanbox of this code-idea.](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-frost-tqbl4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
"use strict"
import ModuleC from '../lib/c'

export default class A extends ModuloC {

    constructor(){        
        console.log("module a");
        super();
    }

    printA(){

        // HERE it's the dynamic import which it's NOT working
        import('./b.js').then((i)=>{
            let foo=new i();
            foo.printB();
        })

        // Dont work too :(
        // const lazy = async () =>{
        //     const module = await import ("./b.js");
        //     module.printB();
        // }
        // lazy();
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
module a
modulo c 
painting module a 
module b
get inside from the promise: painting module b
```

**Error output console screenshot:**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i is not a constructor

[image: error output console]

**Thoughts up:**

```
1) Maybe in ES6 it can't be done, and if in ES5?? (or other javascript class way)
2) Or there is still no way to achieve this yet ...
```

**Technologies i'm using**:

- babel 7.7.7
- webpack 4.41.5
- ES6 javascript
- packages config json below.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    **"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.7.4",**
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-webpack": "webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js",
    "build-babel": "babel src -d lib --watch"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
  }
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {    
    filename: 'bundle-salida.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      minSize: 0
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: None? anybody? :(